# Non-dual BIOS MoBo wont post after BIOS update.... is there nothing that can be done?

Tags: bios, motherboard

My Mobo is gigabyte DS3H B450, its a basic Mobo...
I attempted to update to newer BIOS version for  Ryzen 3000 support, I didnt skip any version, it was the very next version after my current BIOS version.

Using @bios tool in windows (which looks like it's 20 years old...) I loaded in the new bios file, the PC rebooted after it finished but now it wont even enter bios, just fans spinning that's all, no video output.

I tried all the obvious stuff, clearing CMOS, disconnecting stuff one by one, didnt help.
I read about loading backup Bios and tried the methods but it did nothing, there is only one bios chip on this MoBo so not sure it would do anything.

Is there really nothing else that can be done? You are expected to buy the higher end MoBos if you want a guarantee they wont brick themselves after a BIOS update?

Answer (score 3):

Most Ryzen motherboards have BIOS chips too small to fit support for all Ryzen CPUs, so newer BIOSes are starting to drop support for older CPUs. It's possible that the BIOS flash succeeded, but your current CPU isn't supported by this version. Try swapping the CPU for a 3000 series one.

Comment: I dont have a 3000 CPU yet , It is ryzen 1700... but it seems hard to believe gigabyte would be that careless without even giving a warning?

Comment: @blofi It seems unlikely, but at the end of the day mistakes happen. Someone may have forgotten to put appropriate information on the website. This entire situation was an unpleasant surprise for board manufacturers - some have even promised unlimited upgradeability as long as AM4 socket is in use, not anticipating that they'll run out of chip space.

Comment: Ive read some posts that imply their ryzen 1700 was working with 1.0.0.2 BIOS for 3000 series, I am a little concerned about buying 3000 without being sure its just incompatiable BIOS. 

apparently some have flashed bios chip using an arduino, I wasnt sure if this was feasible with ryzen BIOS as the only examples with were old MoBos but there was one example of someone doing it on with ryzen. While the mobo+CPU have become got more advanced they still use the same old SPI chips for BIOS

Comment: Unless you're absolutely determined to do this yourself and you don't mind bricking the motherboard if things go south, I'd avoid flashing the BIOS chip directly.

Comment: i just found out that this bios version should work with the 1700, so its already bricked unfortunately